# Проверить куку на целочисленность

Tags: php

Как проверить, что значение в куке является целочисленным?

В куке ST содержится значение 1572899812.
Пытаюсь так:

```
if (is_int(1572899812)) echo 111;
if (is_int($_COOKIE['ST'])) echo 222;
```

В выводе получаю только 111.

Comment: В куке всегда хранятся строки.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cookies хранит только строки (см. документацию по `setcookie`). Если есть необходимость, то можете попробовать делать преобразование в `int`. Для вашей задачи подойдет проверка на `is_numeric`, которая проверяет, является ли переменная числом или строкой, содержащей число. При этом, строка `12a3` выдаст `false`.

Answer (score 0):

`is_int()` или `is_integer()` проверяют параметр по типу, то есть перданный параметр должен быть типом *int*, для вашей задачи можно использовать [is_numeric()](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.is-numeric.php), или же если нужно только ***целое число*** то можно использовать регулярное выражение

```
if(preg_match('@^[0-9]+@', $cookie)){ 
    // ...
}
```

Так как для строки "**100.99**" `is_numeric()` вернет `true`

Answer (score 0):

Используйте функцию [ctype_digit](https://php.net/ctype_digit), она как раз предназначена для проверки строки на наличие только цифр.